# Why does the fragment_container control fill in whole screen in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are two controls, both `nav_view` and `fragment_container`.

I hope that `nav_view` is located on the bottom of screen , and `fragment_container` fill in the free space, so I write Code A.

But I find `fragment_container` fill in the whole screen, you can see Image A, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: In your xml, change height in fragment from android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="0dp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `match_parent` into `fragment` tag is taking the whole screen (as your navbar is not visible). For `ConstarintLayout` you need to use `match_constraints` instead match_parent to achieve what you want. *Hello World is perfect in his comment.*

Use below code

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Comment: Thank you! your code works well, but is there a keyword named `match_constraints` ?  does `0dp` mean  `match_constraints` ?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes. match_constraints having value 0. Read more at https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#adjust-the-view-size